# How do I include a javascript file in Wordpress admin Widgets

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a widget for wordpress. The form of the widget has some input boxes. Now, I want to add a custom input box which uses a javascript file I downloaded from http://jscolor.com/

Now, the problem is, it is not working. I have registered the javascript file like this in the form function of the WP_Widget class.

```
require_once('index.php');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'pw_load_scripts');
```

The pw_load_scripts function is in index.php

```
function pw_load_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('custom-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'scripts/jscolor.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js');
}
```

After all these, it is not working. What is the correct way to do this task?

My error.log has this error

```
[Mon Oct 07 21:37:30.591896 2013] [:error] [pid 14853] [client 127.0.0.1:42453] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare _wp_menu_output() (previously declared in /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/menu-header.php:36) in /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/menu-header.php on line 36
```

Thank you

Comment: What does the PHP error log say, or what other visible errors do you see?

Comment: In widgets.php, only widgets till above and left of my widget can be seen. Others cannot be seen.

Comment: What does the PHP error log say, and also the Javascript console.  Please check both and make sure there are no errors.

Comment: This is the error I get in error log ' [Mon Oct 07 21:37:30.591896 2013] [:error] [pid 14853] [client 127.0.0.1:42453] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare _wp_menu_output() (previously declared in /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/menu-header.php:36) in /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/menu-header.php on line 36'

Comment: That's a *Fatal Error*, meaning that the site wouldn't be working... I guess it's not related, and it's dated from October anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The <strike>correct</strike> hook is [`admin_print_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts) <sup>**1**</sup> to enqueue styles *and* scripts.

Note that `admin_footer` and `admin_head` also accept the same screen targeting `'actionname-$hook'`:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-widgets.php', 'admin_enqueue_so_19228543' );

function admin_enqueue_so_19228543()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 
            'my-script', 
            plugins_url( '/my-script.js', __FILE__ ), 
            array(), // dependencies
            false, // version
            true // on footer
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 
        'my-style', plugins_url( '/my-style.css', __FILE__ ) 
    );

}
```

<sub>**1** The Codex is saying otherwise, but I was pretty sure this was an official stance. I'm researching and will report back.</sub>

---

***update***

I cannot find any reference to `admin_print_scripts` being the correct hook, although it works and I've seen used this way many times. For completeness, this is how `admin_enqueue_scripts` works:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_enqueue_so_19228543' );

function admin_enqueue_so_19228543( $hook )
{
    if( 'widgets.php' != $hook )
        return;

    wp_enqueue_script( 
            'my-script', 
            plugins_url( '/my-script.js', __FILE__ ), 
            array(), // dependencies
            false, // version
            true // on footer
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 
        'my-style', plugins_url( '/my-style.css', __FILE__ ) 
    );

}
```

<sub>Related: [Difference between do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix) and do_action(“admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix”) syntax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/49993/12615)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Try removing:

```
require_once('index.php');
```

I'm not sure where you got this from.  It appears to be trying to reload wordpress' index.php file.

Comment: Hey thanks, the error got removed. But, the color picker is still not working. It is just a normal input box.

Comment: Does your input element look like: <input class="color">